# How to delete all attributes from the schema in solr?

Tags: windows, curl, solr

Deleting all documents from solr is

```
curl http://localhost:8983/solr/trans/update?commit=true -d "<delete><query>*:*</query></delete>"
```

Adding a (static) attribute to the schema is

```
curl -X POST -H 'Content-type:application/json' --data-binary '{ "add-field":{"name":"trans","type":"string","stored":true, "indexed":true},}' http://localhost:8983/solr/trans/schema
```

Deleting one attribute is

```
curl -X POST -H 'Content-type:application/json' -d '{ "delete-field":{"name":"trans"}}' http://arteika:8983/solr/trans/schema
```

Is there a way to delete all attributes from the schema?

Comment: I wonder if doing it through managed-schema were an option

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?

Answer (score 2):

At least in version 6.6 of the Schema API and up to the current version 7.5 of it, you can pass multiple commands in a single post (see [6.6](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/schema-api.html#SchemaAPI-MultipleCommandsinaSinglePOST) and [7.5](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_5/schema-api.html#multiple-commands-in-a-single-post) documenation, respectively). There are multiple accepted formats, but the most intuitive one (I think) is just passing an array for the action you want to perform:

```sh
curl -X POST -H 'Content-type: application/json' -d '{
  "delete-field": [
    {"name": "trans"},
    {"name": "other_field"}
  ]
}' 'http://arteika:8983/solr/trans/schema'
```

So. How do we obtain the names of the fields we want to delete? That can be done by querying the Schema:

```sh
curl -X GET -H 'Content-type: application/json' 'http://arteika:8983/solr/trans/schema'
```

In particular, the `copyFields`, `dynamicFields` and `fields` keys in the `schema` object in the response.

I automated clearing all copy field rules, dynamic field rules and fields as follows. You can of course use any kind of script that is available to you. I used Python 3 (might work with Python 2, I did not test that).

```python
import json
import requests

# load schema information
api = 'http://arteika:8983/solr/trans/schema'
r = requests.get(api)

# delete copy field rules
names = [(o['source'], o['dest']) for o in r.json()['schema']['copyFields']]
payload = {'delete-copy-field': [{'source': name[0], 'dest': name[1]} for name in names]}
requests.post(api, data = json.dumps(payload),
                   headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json'})

# delete dynamic fields
names = [o['name'] for o in r.json()['schema']['dynamicFields']]
payload = {'delete-dynamic-field': [{'name': name} for name in names]}
requests.post(api, data = json.dumps(payload),
                   headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json'})

# delete fields
names = [o['name'] for o in r.json()['schema']['fields']]
payload = {'delete-field': [{'name': name} for name in names]}
requests.post(api, data = json.dumps(payload),
                   headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json'})
```

Just a note: I received status 400 responses at first, with `null` error messages. Had a bit of a hard time figuring out how to fix those, so I'm sharing what worked for me. Changing the default of `updateRequestProcessorChain` in `solrconfig.xml` to `false` (`default="${update.autoCreateFields:false}"`) and restarting the Solr service made those errors go away for me. The fields I was deleting were created automatically, that may have something to do with that.